# How should I share a large read-only List<T> with each Task.Factory.StartNew() method

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, taskfactory

Consider that I have a custom class called `Terms` and that class contains a number of strings properties. Then I create a fairly large (say 50,000) `List<Terms>` object. This `List<Terms>` only needs to be read from but it needs to be read from by multiple instances of `Task.Factory.StartNew` (the number of instances could vary from 1 to 100s).

How would I best pass that list into the long running task? Memory isn't too much of a concern as this is a custom application for a specific use on a specific server with plenty of memory. Should I reference it or should I just pass it off as a normal argument into the method doing the work?

Comment: As an option you can divide the list into multiple parts and read from them separately, but I agree with @KenSmith

Comment: If you are reading from list only - they passing by ref or normal parameter would have the same effect since List is an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as you don't try to *copy* it into each separate task, it shouldn't make much difference: more a matter of coding style than anything else. Each task will still be working with the same list in memory: just a different reference to the same underlying list.

That said, sheerly as a matter of coding style and maintainability, I'd probably try to pass it in as a parameter to whatever method you're executing in your `Task.Factory.StartNew()` (or better yet, `Task.Run()` - see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx)). That way, you've clearly called out your task's dependencies, and if you decide that you need to get the list from some other place, it's more clear what you've got to change. (But you could probably find 20 places in my own code where I haven't followed that rule: sometimes I go with what's easier for me now than with what's likely to be easier for the me six months from now.)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're passing a reference it doesn't really matter how you pass it, it won't copy the list itself. As Ket Smith said, I would pass it as a parameter to the method you are executing.

The issue is `List<T>` is not entirely thread-safe. Reads by multiple threads are safe but a write can cause some issues:

> It is safe to perform multiple read operations on a List, but issues can occur if the collection is modified while it’s being read. **To ensure thread safety, lock the collection during a read or write operation**.

From [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)

You say your list is read-only so that may be a non-issue, but a single unpredictable change could lead to unexpected behavior and so it's bug-prone.

I recommend using [`ImmutableList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467185(v=vs.110).aspx) which is **inherently thread-safe** since it's immutable.

Comment: Agreed about using the `ImmutableList<T>`. Never trust your own code :-).